# R Disable layer in Plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have a plot with multiple lines and would like to initialize it with just some layers active. Is it possible? Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
    set.seed(101)
    df <- data.frame(x = seq(1,20,1),
                     y1 = runif(20),
                     y2 = runif(20),
                     y3 = runif(20),
                     y4 = runif(20))
    
    plot_ly(df, x = ~x) %>%
      add_lines(y = ~y1, name='y1', line = list(color = 'rgba(255,0,0,1')) %>%
      add_lines(y = ~y2, name='y2', line = list(color = 'rgba(0,255,0,1')) %>%
      add_lines(y = ~y3, name='y3', line = list(color = 'rgba(106,90,205,1')) %>%
      add_lines(y = ~y4, name='y4', line = list(color = 'rgba(0,0,255,1')) %>%
        layout(
        xaxis = list(title = "x", domain = c(0,1), tickmode = 'auto'),
        yaxis = list(title = 'y', side = "left", color = "black", position = 0,
                     anchor = 'free', range = c(0,1), dtick = 1),
        showlegend = T
    )
```

What I want is to generate a plot with all lines, but e.g. with y3 and y4 off and still allow the user to turn it on (this plot is part of a shiny app).

Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `visible = "legendonly"` for the traces you want to hide:

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1,20,1),
                 y1 = runif(20),
                 y2 = runif(20),
                 y3 = runif(20),
                 y4 = runif(20))

plot_ly(df, x = ~x) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~y1, name='y1', line = list(color = 'rgba(255,0,0,1')) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~y2, name='y2', line = list(color = 'rgba(0,255,0,1')) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~y3, name='y3', line = list(color = 'rgba(106,90,205,1'), visible = "legendonly") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~y4, name='y4', line = list(color = 'rgba(0,0,255,1'), visible = "legendonly") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "x", domain = c(0,1), tickmode = 'auto'),
    yaxis = list(title = 'y', side = "left", color = "black", position = 0,
                 anchor = 'free', range = c(0,1), dtick = 1),
    showlegend = TRUE
  )
```

To get more information regarding the available trace attributes use:

`schema()`

and navigate as follows:

object ► traces ► scatter ► attributes